# Android Device Not Detecting In Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, emulation, android-virtual-device

I am trying to run my application on my Device from the Eclipse In windows.But my device is not detecting there in the eclipse.

My device driver is updated. In My device, I turned on **"USB debugging mode"** in Settings->Application->Development and also  **"Allow installation of non-market Applications"** in Settings->Application->Development. And in Eclipse Target tab, selected **"Always prompt to select device"**. My **ProjectBuildTarget** is not newer than my device's version. And tried **adb kill-server** also.

When i run  **adb devices** it shows nothing in my command prompt.

How do I get Eclipse to load my app to my phone instead of my AVD?

When i tried it in my Mac machine It works perfectly..

Any solutions? Please suggest me..

Comment: Try to uninstall and reinstall your Sony driver that comes with your Sony Xperia phone or use Sony Companion application to properly detect the right driver when it detects a different mode used in a Sony device. Other than that, check where your are using the right USB mode (I am not sure what USB mode is available on Sony Xperia mini...it is quite old already). In newer Xperias, it can be either MTP or MSC

Comment: Other approach which usually works well for uncommon OEM devices, by using PDANet driver http://preetprasannan.wordpress.com/2013/07/13/install-adb-drivers-for-android-if-oem-drivers-not-working-not-present/

Comment: If you don't like PDANet driver, check back your System Device Manager (I assume you are running Windows) and check USB device with driver issue (usually overlaid with a yellow warning sign) and uninstall it. I assume that you have already installed Sony Companion and have rebooted your system. Unplug the USB cable from Xperia mini and replug it. Windows shall try to detect the correct USB driver when you are connecting in USB debugging mode.

Comment: As a note, it doesn't matter which mode it is (MTP or MSC), as long as the correct driver (Sony ADB Interface driver) is detected for USB debugging mode. When it is not in USB debugging mode, the correct USB driver is just a MTP driver (in MTP mode) or "USB Mass Storage Device" (in MSC mode).

Comment: http://www.sonymobile.com/gb/tools/pc-companion/ ...this software helps to detect correct driver to use...but it only works for USB 2.0 or less, but I am not sure whether it works for USB 3.0 or not.

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following:

1. Go to settings in your phone
2. Go to storage menu
3. Select connect as MTP

Worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a MAC OS.... no need to install the Driver

But for Windows, try this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#RealDevice

Comment: I am using Windows and my device is Sony Experia mini with android 2.3.4. When i click Run as and proceed only the virtual devices are showing.

Answer (score 1):

[Debugging to phone](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)

Please see the link above, the process is defined there from google.

Answer (score 1):

try deleting your AVD and leave your phone connected, then restart your IDE. Make sure you've downloaded the OEM USB drivers. If it still doesn't appear on the list, hit refresh then just run your app.

Answer (score 1):

close you AVD if its running, then re-plug your Mobile device, check in your phone USB debugging notification should come.

Comment: In my device the notification shouldn't come. I turned on USB debugging mode from settings.

Comment: then it  should be there,i think you re-try to connect your device